# Vue Components are not loaded in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-install

I tried to integrate Vue.js to Laravel. However I face one problem. Even though I did everything correctly but the Vue Components are not showing in my php blade.

Code for app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

All the php codes are working just fine on the browser, only the vue component is not able to show up on my browser.

Code in my contact-us.blade:

```
<div id="app">
    <example></example>
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<section class="site-content">
    <style>
        #map_wrapper {
            /*height: 300px;*/
            clear: both;
        }
        #googleMap {
            margin-top:0px!important;
            /*width: 100%!important;*/
            /*height: 100%!important;*/
        }
    </style>
    @if(isset($result['site_key']))
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{$result['site_key']}}"></script>
    @endif

    <div id="map_wrapper">
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:380px; margin-top:-30px; margin-bottom:30px; "></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcum-area">
            <div class="breadcum-inner">
                <h3>@lang('website.Contact Us')</h3>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ URL::to('/')}}">@lang('website.Home')</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">@lang('website.Contact Us')</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-area">
            <div class="heading">
                <h2>@lang('website.Contact Us')</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
                     @if(session()->has('success') )
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session()->get('success') }}
                        </div>
                     @elseif(session()->has('error') )
                         <div class="alert alert-danger">
                             {{ session()->get('error') }}
                         </div>
                     @endif
                    <form name="signup" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ URL::to('/processContactUs')}}" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstName">@lang('website.Full Name')</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control field-validate" id="name" name="name">
                            <span class="help-block error-content" hidden>@lang('website.Please enter your name')</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputEmail4" class="col-form-label">@lang('website.Email')</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control email-validate" id="inputEmail4" name="email">
                            <span class="help-block error-content" hidden>@lang('website.Please enter your valid email address')</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject" class="col-form-label">@lang('website.Message')</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control field-validate" id="message" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
                            <span class="help-block error-content" hidden>@lang('website.Please enter your message')</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">@lang('website.Send')</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
                    </form>


                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">

                    <ul class="contact-list">
                    @if(!empty(trim(settings('company_name'))) || !empty(trim(settings('company_registration_number'))))
                      <li> <i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i><span>@if(!empty(trim(settings('company_name')))){{settings('company_name')}}@endif @if(!empty(trim(settings('company_registration_number'))))({{settings('company_registration_number')}})@endif</span> </li>
                    @endif
                      <li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>{{settings('address')}} {{settings('city')}} {{settings('state')}}, {{settings('zip')}} {{settings('country')}}</span> </li>
                    @if(!empty(settings('phone_no')))
                      <li> <i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>{{settings('phone_no')}}</span> </li>
                    @endif
                    @if(!empty(settings('contact_us_email')))
                      <li> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span> <a href="mailto:{{settings('contact_us_email')}}">{{settings('contact_us_email')}}</a> </span> </li>
                    @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if(isset($result['site_key']))
    <script>
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('{{$result['site_key']}}', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById("token").value=token;
            });
        });
    </script>
    @endif
</section>
@endsection
```

For vue file, I did not make any changes to it, it is created by default when I created the laravel project.

Code for Example.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component! testing
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried some of the solutions that I found on Google such as using the commands that I listed below but unfortunately none of them work.

```
npm install
npm update 
del package-lock.json
rd /s /q node_modules
npm cache clear --force
```

Does anyone detect the mistake that I made here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only register 'example' component in your app.js file starting with Vue.component('example'.... Usually there is a code section in there which is commented out but if you uncomment it, it will globally register all Vue components for you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue').default);
```

with the following code

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i);
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default));
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `npm run dev && npm run hot`.

Be sure that your component is correctly registered.

Check your console.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend